# For Loop Expression Result Unused but code still works what's wrong?

Tags: c

For Loop Expression Result Unused in xcode
but code still works I don't want to show the whole loop i just need the last number it gets to what's wrong why the warning message ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
// how much memory float consumes

printf("a float consumes %zu bytes\n\n", sizeof(float));

// what is the smallest number a short can hold and its largest

short x;
short y;

for (x; x > -1; x++) {
    continue;
}

for (y; y < 1; y--) {
    continue;
}

printf("\nSmallest short %d\nlargest short %d\n", x, y);

// same question but unsigned short instead

unsigned short i;

for (i; i < 1; i--) {
    continue;
}
printf("largest unsigned short is %d\n", i);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `limits.h`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not initialize `x`, `y`, or `i` so they do not store coherent values and it's nonsense to use them in expressions. The compiler detects this kind of condition, known as *undefined behavior*, and flags the expressions as unused *because they are useless*.

The first fix is to initialize the variables.

```
short x = 0;
short y = 0;
```

The second problem is that the conditions are still nonsense, even if you do start from zero.

```
for (x; x > -1; x++) { // Keep adding one as long as the result is positive.
// But one plus any positive number is always positive.

for (y; y < 1; y--) { // Keep subtracting one as long as the result is negative.
// But any negative number minus one is always negative.
```

The program is based on a common misconception, that integer types wrap around from the maximum value to the minimum value when addition generates a carry into the sign bit. Although this often happens in practice, it is classified as *undefined behavior* and usually considered a computational malfunction, not a feature. Wraparound *may* be guaranteed by a particular compiler, as documented by its manual. C++ even provides a way to inspect this, namely `std::numeric_limits::is_modulo`. However, Clang and most other modern compilers instead opt to assume, for purposes of static analysis, that overflow does not occur and addition of positive numbers only produces positive numbers. Leading the compiler to make a faulty assumption may cause it to produce a faulty executable. This may be a second, independent reason for the warning message.

(Unsigned types *do* always wrap around from the maximum value to zero. The third loop should work, although you don't actually need a loop but `(unsigned short) -1` would do the trick.)

To cleanly find the limits of `short` and `unsigned short`, use this:

```
#include <limits.h>

short smin = SHRT_MIN, smax = SHRT_MAX;
unsigned short usmax = USHRT_MAX;
```

Comment: On top of this, with correctly initialised loop counters it still causes undefined behaviour since the loops never exit until `x` and `y` overflow. It *may* throw the same warning for the new problem.

Comment: Thanks man you made me understand it perfectly!
the reason behind using loops is that, this program is made based on a challenge so they don't want lazy/fast calculations for the limits...

Answer (score 1):

What Potatoswatter said is correct, the immediate problem is that `x`, `y` and `i` are not initialised, so the compiler can either skip the loops or use whatever garbage happens to be in those registers at runtime.

However, even if they were correctly initialised, the behaviour of signed integer overflow is *also* undefined in C and C++, so the loops may function as intended (wrapping around till the sign flips) or not, or the compiler may choose to completely ignore them altogether.

**DO NOT** rely on signed integers wrapping around. Here be dragons.